# How much should I pay in this poker game to make the expectation zero?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, expected-value

I am new to the idea of expectation, and I want to make sure that I understand it. I came across this question stating:

> You are playing a version of poker where you are dealt five cards and you would win $100 if you are dealt a three of a kind. Otherwise you will lose and you have to pay some amount of money. How much money should you have to pay to make this game a fair game (i.e. have expected value \$0)?

So if I have understood expectation correctly, the expectation of this kind of poker game would be: 
$$
\mathbb{E}[x] = -m\left(1-\frac{{13 \choose 1} \cdot {4 \choose 3} \cdot  {12 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose1}^2}{52\choose 5}\right)
                +100\left(\frac{{13 \choose 1} \cdot {4 \choose 3} \cdot  {12 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose1}^2}{52\choose 5}\right)
$$
Where $m$ is the amount of money that we have to pay in this game, then I would set the expectation to zero and solve for $m$?

Comment: I can't follow your calculation.  Are you saying that there are $13\times 12\times 4^3$ ways to get three-of-a-kind?  That's not right.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I made a mistake there. Will fix it now. Thank you.

Comment: If you have four of the art do you win or lose?

Comment: @user you would lose.

Comment: You have wrongly computed the probability to win.

Comment: @user can you help me understand where my mistake is? This is how I based my calculations on: we first chose the rank of the matching cards for the three of a kind and that is 13C1, then we have the ranks of the non-matching cards and that's 12C2. We need suits for the three-card combination and that is 4C3, then we choose a suit for one non-matching card which is 4C1 and for the other non-matching card it would also be 4C1, multiply all these together divide by the total number of possible 5-card combinations, 52C5.

Comment: You have missed the case when both "rest" cards are of the same rank. The simplest correction is to replace $\binom{12}2\binom41^2$ with $\binom{48}2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $p$ is the probability of success you get 
$$
0 = \mathbb{E}[X] = 100p-m(1-p) \iff m = \frac{100p}{1-p}
$$
and it only remains to find $p$...